# Styling handles/control points on polyline in edit mode

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to change the style of the white squares that are used as vertex handles by default when a polyline is set to editable:true?

I can see that changing the stroke of the polyline affects those handle squares, but I'd like to either change the shape of handle (e.g. to a circle), or substitute an image.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've managed to found is a direct manipulation of DOM elements corresponding to those markers. For instance, they may be selected using

```
$('div').filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('width') == '11px';
})
```

Probably, more reliable approach is a DOM tree traverse starting from $('.gm-style') element.